# WPF: Notify nested properties changed

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a collection of class `A`, and this class `A` has a property called `Type`. Based on the value of `Type` the background of the corresponding visual item in the view will change. I am implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the `ViewModel`, but I do not want for class `A` to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Also using `ObservableCollection` will effect the performance. Now the question is how can I notify the view that the property `Type` has changed?

Comment: "*but I do not want for class A to implement INotifyPropertyChanged*" - however, this is exactly what you have to do.

Comment: @Clemens, Yes this one I know of, but I would like to keep my models separated from MVVM concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now the question is how can I notify the view that the property `Type` has changed?

Either implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `Type` or don't bind directly to a property of `Type` but to a property of `A` that wraps the property of `Type`, e.g.:

```
private Type _type = new Type();
public string Name
{
    get { return _type.Name; }
    set { _type.Name = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

Comment: But this means that `A` will implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Any other solutions?

Comment: Wrap `A` in a property of the view model that does implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. That's basically what I was trying to say in my answer.